# How to cancel jQuery.ajax complete depending on the response?

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

#### Situation

My php callback function sends - if no results were found in the DB - back the following:

```
header( "Content-Type: application/json" );
echo json_encode( array(
     'success'  => false
    ,'error'    => 'No results'
) );
exit;
```

#### Problem

When sending back the JSON encoded string, then I can intercept without a probem during the `.success()` function and simply return and open a dialog.

What doesn't work is intercepting the `.complete()` function, that gets triggered *after* `success/error` were triggered. Inside the `complete` function, I have `status = success` and can only see my `error` inside `jqxhr.responseText` formatted as string: `"{"success":false,"error":"No results"}"`.

I can't use `error` as it's not a `404/whatever`. It's just *No results*.

#### Question: How can I intercept and cancel/abort `complete`?

When I'd now go and add `substring` checking for all sorts of error messages, I'd get mad.

<sup>Notes: I'm using jQuery in combination with jQuery Mobile.</sup>

---

The Data gets process by `$.ajax()` like the following (simplified example):

```
$.ajax( {
     type:      'POST'
    ,url:       my_object.ajaxurl
    ,data:      my_data
    ,success:   function( response, status, request )
     {
        if ( false == response.success )
        {
            $( '#note h3' ).html( response.error );

            return $.mobile.changePage( '#note', 'pop', true, true );
        }

        // Markers
        doStuffWith( response.data );

        $.mobile.changePage( $( '#another_view' ) );
     }
    ,error:     function( jqxhr , settings , exception )
     {

     }
    ,complete: function( jqxhr, status )
     {
        console.log( jqxhr );
        console.log( status );
        // @TODO ABORT IF ERROR
        $( '#list_canvas' ).listview( 'refresh' );
     }
} );
```

Answer (score 0):

Just call your listview refresh at the end of the success callback, and remove the complete callback.

Comment: Sadly this doesn't work and doesn't update the list. It's known bug ending up in either `Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'listview'` or `uncaught exception: cannot call methods on listview prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'refresh'`. I have to do it there in order to let it work. The only possible other solution would be to do an expensive `.find()` and completely rebuild the list.

Answer (score 0):

If you'd [read up](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) on what the complete function parameters return, you'd see that among those messages is a `success` message. The complete callback is executed after the success/error functions have been executed. Since you're not even using the error function, there's no reason why you couldn't put it in the success function.

So you could do this

```
complete: function( jqxhr, status )
 {
    console.log( jqxhr );
    console.log( status );

    if(status == "success"){
        $( '#list_canvas' ).listview( 'refresh' );
    }
 }
```

Or just dump the whole complete callback altogether and do the refresh in the success function

```
success:   function( response, status, request )
 {
    if ( false == response.success )
    {
        $( '#note h3' ).html( response.error );

        return $.mobile.changePage( '#note', 'pop', true, true );
    }

    // Markers
    doStuffWith( response.data );

    $.mobile.changePage( $( '#another_view' ) );
    $( '#list_canvas' ).listview( 'refresh' );
 }
```

If you're getting an error because you're trying to refresh a listview that is not yet initialized, then you should focus on initializing the listview *before* you do any AJAX calls.